# Senha segura em PHP (Verificação de senha)

Tags: php, regex

Como faço para verificar se minha senha esta segura ou não?
Tenho um código em PHP de verificação, só que não sei fazer **verificação da senha**. 
Ela deveria ser:

1. Ter mais de 6 caracteres (Feito em HTML);
2. Conter Letras maiúsculas e minúsculas;
3. Conter Números.

```php
<?php
 use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

    session_start();

    require '../PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
    require '../PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
    require '../PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

    $avatar = "images/avatar/default.png";

    $nome = "";
    $email= "";
    $senha = "";
    $SalvarSenha = "";
    $receberEmail = "";

    include ("../../assets/util/conn.php"); // Minha conexao PDO

    //Verificar se foi metodo POST Usado e se o Metodo veido do FORM Registrar
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['Registrar']))
    {
        unset($_SESSION['email']);
        unset($_SESSION['status']);

        $nome = addslashes($_POST['nome']);
        $email = addslashes($_POST['email']);
        $senha = md5(addslashes($_POST['senha']));
        $receberEmail = isset($_POST['termos']) ? 1 : 0;
        $SalvarSenha = $_POST['senha'];

        //Verificar as senhas contem numero e letra ERRADO AINDA
        if (!preg_match('/[A-Za-z]/', $SalvarSenha) || !preg_match('/[0-9]/', $SalvarSenha))
        {
            echo "Senha tem que conter letras e números.";
        }
.
.
.
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Os colchetes definem uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Quando você faz `[A-Za-z]`, isso significa "uma letra de `a` a `z` **ou** de `A` a `Z`". Ou seja, pode tanto ser uma letra minúscula quanto maiúscula.

Então se tiver uma maiúscula, mas nenhuma minúscula (ou vice-versa), esta regex deixa passar. Para obrigar que tenha pelo menos uma de cada (tem que ter uma maiúscula **e** uma minúscula), e além disso obrigar que também tenha um número, e que tenha pelo menos 6 caracteres, você tem 2 alternativas.

#### 1- verificar cada condição separadamente

Para cada condição, podemos fazer um `preg_match` diferente. O detalhe é o critério "deve ter pelo menos 6 caracteres". Já sabemos que letras e números são obrigatórios, mas quais caracteres a senha poderá ter? Vai permitir caracteres especiais? Acentos? Emojis? E por aí vai. Quanto mais opções, [mais difícil é a regex](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/emoji-regex/blob/v7.0.3/es2015/index.js#L5).

Apenas para simplificar, vamos assumir que a senha pode ter letras, números, `_`, `@` e `$`. **Isso é apenas para exemplificar**, já que limitar demais os caracteres permitidos diminui a quantidade de senhas possíveis, mas permitir demais pode levar a casos em que o usuário terá dificuldades em digitar novamente a senha, conforme discutido [nesta pergunta do Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/2096).

Enfim, para letras, números e `_` podemos usar o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\w`. Já para `@` e `$`, podemos usar os próprios caracteres, então a expressão fica `[\w$@]` (novamente, isso é apenas para simplificar o exemplo - adicione todos os caracteres que precisar dentro dos colchetes). E para o tamanho, usamos `{6,}`, que significa "6 ou mais ocorrências". Ou seja, deve ter pelo menos 6 caracteres. O código ficaria assim:

```
function senhaValida($senha) {
    return preg_match('/[a-z]/', $senha) // tem pelo menos uma letra minúscula
     && preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $senha) // tem pelo menos uma letra maiúscula
     && preg_match('/[0-9]/', $senha) // tem pelo menos um número
     && preg_match('/^[\w$@]{6,}$/', $senha); // tem 6 ou mais caracteres
}

var_dump(senhaValida('aB1@xy$z')); // true
var_dump(senhaValida('aB1')); // false, não tem 6 caracteres
var_dump(senhaValida('AB1@XYZ')); // false, não tem letra minúscula
var_dump(senhaValida('ab1@xyz')); // false, não tem letra maiúscula
var_dump(senhaValida('ABc@xyz')); // false, não tem número
```

Repare que para o tamanho eu também usei os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`, que significam respectivamente o início e fim da string. Com isso eu garanto que, do início ao fim, existem pelo menos 6 ocorrências dos caracteres que eu defini (e apenas desses caracteres).

As outras condições não precisam de `^` e `$`, pois eu só estou verificando se os caracteres existem em qualquer posição da string.

O código imprime `bool(true)` para a primeira senha, e `bool(false)` para as demais.

---

#### 2- fazer tudo em uma regex só

Para isso, temos que usar [*lookaheads*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). A ideia do *lookahead* é verificar uma expressão, e em seguida voltar para onde estava e prosseguir com o restante da regex. Ela fica assim:

```
function senhaValida($senha) {
    return preg_match('/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[\w$@]{6,}$/', $senha);
}
```

Primeiro temos `^` (o início da string). Em seguida temos um *lookahead*, que começa com `(?=`. Dentro dele temos `.*[a-z]`, que significa "zero ou mais ocorrências de qualquer caractere" (`.*`), seguido de uma letra minúscula (`[a-z]`). Ou seja, este *lookahead* verifica se existe uma letra minúscula na string.

O truque do *lookahead* é que, depois que ele verifica se a letra minúscula existe, ele volta para onde estava (ou seja, para o início da string) e verifica o restante da expressão. E no restante, temos outro *lookahead* para verificar se há uma letra maiúscula, e depois outro para verificar se há um número. Se algum dos *lookaheads* falhar, a regex como um todo também falha.

E em seguida temos a expressão que verifica se há pelo menos 6 caracteres, seguido do final da string (`$`). Ou seja, ela faz todas as verificações do exemplo anterior de uma só vez.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funcionou!